# Nature of urea and it's relation with uric acid

Tags: acid-base, nomenclature

My question is what is the nature of urea. I checked it on the Internet and according to my results, the nature of urea is basic. Then why is there uric acid? For example when we add magnesium oxide to water, magnesium hydroxide (a base) is formed. Similarly when we add sulfur trioxide to water, sulfuric acid is formed. Thus, if the nature of the substance decides whether it will form an acid or a base then why is this case not followed by urea as urea is basic but it forms uric acid?

Comment: Uric acid is not what you get when you add water to urea. Go and look at the structures of the two compounds.

Answer (score 1):

The names of *uric acid* and *urea* are both derived from *urine* in some way which is whence the chemicals were first discovered. This is even more evident in e.g. their German names *Harnstoff* (urea) and *Harnsäure* (uric acid), literally meaning urine-compound and urine-acid. They have no further relationship.

Apart from uric acid containing the word *acid*, there is no clue as to the acidic or basic property given in the name.